# How to join using lowercase dimensions in BigQuery

Tags: join, key, google-bigquery, lowercase

I have a BigQuery table of payments with columns for transaction_id, date, customer, zip, and payment_amount

I would like to create a table of customers with a column of total payments, which is a sum of all of the payment_amounts that a customer has made.

Sometimes customers type their names using different capitalization from one purchase to the next, which results in John Smith and JOHN SMITH getting separate rows in my new table, when they are actually the same person.

I would like to figure out a way to create this table where John Smith, JOHN SMITH, and john smith are considered the same customer.
I have tried:

```
SELECT
lower(name) as name_a
,zip
,total_payments
From SweetData.Payments AS a

JOIN EACH

(Select
lower(name) as name_b
,sum(amount) as total_payments
From SweetData.Payments
GROUP BY name_b) As b

ON a.name_a = b.name_b
```

But it gives me an error for using aliases from table 'a' in the ON clause.

So I tried using the function lower() in the ON clause as follows:

```
SELECT
name
,zip
,total_payments
From SweetData.Payments AS a

JOIN EACH

(Select
lower(name) as name_b
,sum(amount) as total_payments
From SweetData.Payments
GROUP BY name_b) As b

ON lower(a.name) = b.name_b
```

But I got an error there as well.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

*EDITED 2*

If I understand your updated request, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    a.name
    , a.zip
    , b.total_payments
FROM (
    SELECT
        lower(name) as name
        ,zip
    From SweetData.Payments
) AS b
JOIN (
    select 
        lower(name) as name
        , sum(payments) as total_payments
    from SweetData.Payments 
    group by 1  
) AS a
ON a.name = b.name
```

Comment: Hey Gil,
Thanks for your reply! My problem is a little more complex than I originally let on, and I'm afraid I distilled it down too far for this post. (Rookie mistake!)
My first table will include dimensions that I will not be grouping the total_payments by, thus I believe I need a join.
See edits for my corrections.
Thanks again!

Comment: I've made changes - how about now?

Comment: Hmmm, that gives me the following error: The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
Field 'total_payments' not found.

I tried fiddling with it, but still couldn't resolve the issue.

Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah, of course - I had the field total_payments in the first query as well. _should_ work now :)